# Removing duplicates in dataset using panda's dataframe.drop_duplicate()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm reading a Twitter dataset I acquired using Python's `csv.reader()`. I noticed that in this dataset, there were duplicate. I'm trying to remove these by using `pandas.drop_duplicate()` function, but am some trouble.

Here is the implementation I've written:

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd


def process_tweet(tweet):

    # lowercase all text
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    # remove additional whitespaces in tweets
    tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
    # remove all hashtags
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', "", tweet)
    # replace all url links to T_URL
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))', 'T_URL', tweet)
    # tweet = re.sub(r"http\S+", "T_URL", tweet)
    tweet = tweet.split('\n')

    remove_duplicates(tweet)

    print tweet,
    print ','  # added this because I needed each of the list, L1,L2..LN, to end with a comma

    return tweet


def remove_duplicates(tweet):

    df = pd.DataFrame(tweet)
    removed_list = df.drop_duplicates()

    # print removed_list;

    return removed_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('../../dataset/data.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for row in reader:
            process_tweet(row[1])

        print '\n End run'
```

When I created a list in iPython containing repeated data (see: `1,2,3`) and a few unique ones (see: `0,4`), `drop_duplicate()`seems to work correctly. Note that I've redacted some data and these are marked as `<removed>`.

```
In [27]: df5
Out[27]:
                                                   0
0  <removed> <removed> forced off course by spa...
1        <removed> adds <removed> to <removed> T_URL
2        <removed> adds <removed> to <removed> T_URL
3        <removed> adds <removed> to <removed> T_URL
4                <removed>   winner    T_URL


In [28]: df5.drop_duplicates()
Out[28]:
                                                   0
0  <removed> <removed> forced off course by spa...
1        <removed> adds <removed> to <removed> T_URL
4                <removed>    winner    T_URL
```

I don't know if this helps but I observed that when I printed my dataframe `df`, every tweet is contained in separate dataframes. Is this a reason why `df.drop_duplicates()`is not working in my implementation?

Please pardon my less than impressive code. Python is new to me and I'm still learning it and the scientic packages on the go.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and for any assistance rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to go a different approach in handling the duplicates using dataframes as my structure entirely. Instead of having to deal with Python's native library of reading CSVs and iterating through every row, I've decided to use pandas inbuilt `read_csv` method and place them in a dataframe. I then used the same method of `drop_duplicate()` to remove repeating data.

I hope that helps future readers.